# Most Efficient Way to Store Bitmap Info Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Currently, I am using a WeakHashMap to store my BitMap and link it to my key, but I have noticed it begins to use a ton of RAM. Is there a better solution to caching the BitMaps till I need them? It is unlikely I will need the image after the application closes, so a long-term solution isn't really needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use-case? Do you download them from the Internet and you need a temporary storage to save user's bandwidth?

Comment: I am downloading the images and displaying them in a ViewPager. I need to keep them in memory in case the user swipes back to a previous view to save bandwidth and make the ViewPager more responsive (no black pages while waiting for an image to re-download).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is unlikely I will need the image after the application closes, so a long-term solution isn't really needed.

Storing images in cache wont be a problem as system doesn't clear image from cache even after you close the application or unless you clear the app data from setting.
For image downloading you can use image libraries like:
Image loaders:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
It gives you option to save image in cache.

You  can also use volley library. But in this you have to implement your own code for cache storing.
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Otherwise you can also implement your own code for cache in which you can use memory disk for caching.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks! I'll look into the memory disk caching, seems like the best solution for my issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to keep them in memory in case the user swipes back to a
>   previous view to save bandwidth and make the ViewPager more responsive

[`FragmentStateAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) is meant for precisely that. Also use [`setOffscreenPageLimit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) and [`setRetainInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) in conjunction with that.

Storing `Bitmap` objects in runtime memory is not a good idea and will sooner or later lead to `OutOfMemoryError`s getting thrown.

Comment: @ccrama: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: I ended up re-writing a lot of my image stuff. I switched to using Picasso which has lead to a 33% reduction in ram usage, which is awesome. Your change also led to another 30-40% reduction in memory, for a grand total of 2/3 less memory used. Thank you!

Comment: Well the person who I marked as correct already helped me with the actual image part which was the question. Yours helped as well so I upvoted it though!

Answer (score 0):

Use an [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).  There are plenty of online [guides](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) on the developer site.